# Is there such a thing as ground "quality"?

Tags: ground

I recently bought a surge-protected outlet which has a light showing when it is not grounded.
At my appartment the light indicating "not grounded" is always on, but when I tested it at work (where I'm certain the very expensive hardware is grounded) it wasn't on.
I had a professionnal come and check my electrical installation at home and he told me that everything was grounded. As for the discrepancy between home and work, he told me that the ground at work was of "better quality".

Does that mean anything? and if it does what does it mean (to a layman)?

Edit: This is in France.

Comment: It means your professional didn't want to be bothered to figure out your outlet's light and gave you a quick guess. In reality, there is a precise reason why the light comes on and you'd need to understand that reason in order to say why it comes on in your home and not at your work. It would help a lot to know what country and/or electrical system you are on and your types of plugs, etc. Systems in Japan, for example, might easily have one quick explanation while systems in the US couldn't be justified that way and would need another explanation, instead. Where you are matters.

Comment: Next time hire a professional that is worth that name.

Comment: Can you put the thing 180° turned into your socket? In my flat I have to put them in a certain way so that it (a multi socket surge protected USB loader crazy thing) tells me it is grounded. Seems to make an assumption which wire is neutral and which is live which doesn't hold up to the installation in my flat.

Comment: @jonk: edited, this is in France

Comment: @Arsenal: there is no way for me to plug it differently.

Comment: In France, I think the house owner has the responsibility of making sure that the property has a properly connected "earth." I don't think EDF or any other company has to do that part. So I think you have a good question, now. You should press forward to get a good, final answer. Your electrician may have been right that your ground is poor, but exists. In the US, code allows for a Ufer ground (rebar embedded in the concrete foundation) but also for deeply placed copper rods near the home. You should find out your situation, I think, and correct it.

Comment: @jonk: ty for your input, I'll try contacting the landlord for a more thorough inspection.

Answer (score 1):

I think by "poor ground quality" he meant excessively high ground-path resistance. Simplest way to measure it (how this socket, I believe, does), is by measuring neutral-to-earth voltage difference. If the difference is high-enough, it lights up